# Javascript / jQuery - Update object from another object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a complex and deep object, `storedData.Department`, which is being used by AngularJS.  When changes occur that need to be reflected in the UI, I am using jQuery's `$.extend()` to merge changes into the existing object from a new object returned from an XHR:

```
$.extend(true, storedData.Department, res.data.Department);
```

This works great when the changes are *additive*.  Unfortunately, any changes that are *subtractive* are not removed from `storedData.Department`.

I can simply overwrite the `storedData.Department` object with the updated object, but that causes a significant performance degradation compared to `$.extend`.

How can I selectively update `storedData.Department`, only adding and removing what has changed in `res.data.Department`?  The solution would need to be reasonably performant.

Comment: You performance issues are due to Angular modal binding. B/c when you overwrite the original object all your property bindings have to update instead of just the ones that changed. As far as pure JS goes changing a pointer can't get any faster. To remove the properties you will have to loop through both objects and do "delete object.property" the ones you don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delete to remove the properties on the original object that are not on the object returned from the XHR call. It's just delete object.property. You'd have to loop through the properties on each object to determine what is present, but that should be pretty performant.

Actually, in a loop, syntax more like this: delete object[propertyName] would probably be the way to go.

Something like this should be pretty close. (I haven't tested it.)

```
function mirror(source, target) {
    // assign all property values from the source to the target.
    for (var prop in source) {
         target[prop] = source[prop];
    };
    // remote any properties present on the target that aren't in the source.
    for (var prop in target) {
        if (! source[prop]) {
            delete target[prop];
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Mike.  Can you elaborate on, "You'd have to loop through the properties on each object to determine what is present"?

Comment: Sure. I updated the answer. If that doesn't work it should be very close.

Comment: Also, angular.copy might just do the trick for you. It deletes all of the properties from the target object first. Since performance is key, you might want to try both approaches and see which is more efficient. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy